# How to add dynamic elements in Owl Carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I have a problem with Owl-carousel when I add dynamic data using vanilla JavaScript it rendered in side `.owl-carousel` but not working.

```
const moreProjects = [
{
 image: "./images/huddle-landing.jpg",
 title: "Huddle landing page",
 desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to practice my layout skills.",
 github:"https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-huddle-landingpage.git",
 preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-huddle-landingpage/",
},
{
 image: "./images/loopstudios-landing.jpg",
 title: "Loopstudios landing page",
 desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to practice my knowledge using CSS Grid.",
 github:"https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-loopstudio.git",
preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-loopstudio/",
},
{
 image: "./images/pricingcomponent.jpg",
 title: "Pricing component",
 desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to increase my knowledge on JavaScript and how to style input range.",
 github:"https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-pricingcomponent.git",
 preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-pricingcomponent/",
},
]

const carouselDOM = document.querySelector(".owl-carousel");

function moreProj(projects){
  let project = projects.map( (project) => {
  const {image, title,desc,github, preview} = project;
   return `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
          <img src="${image}" class="img-fluuid" alt="project image">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="indicator">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-grip-lines"></i>
          </div>
          <h3 class="title">${title}</h3>
          <p class="desc">${desc}</p>
          <div class="links">
            <a href="${github}" class="link" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
              Github
            </a>
            <a href="${preview}" class="link" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
              Preview
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;
  });
   project = project.join("");
   carouselDOM.innerHTML = project;
 }

 moreProj(moreProjects);
```

I need it to render here:

```
 <section class="carousel">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <!-- RENDER ELEMENTS HERE -->
    </div>
  </section>
```

is there a way to solve this problem? Thank you for your time.

This is the output of the code.
[image: my output]

this is my desired output.
[image: desired output]

Comment: Can you  please share the `projects array` you are passing to `moreProj functtion`.

Comment: array of objects added

Comment: No code will run after the return keyword. Move project = project.join("");
            carouselDOM.innerHTML = project;     out of the " } "; I will edit your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Changes I would like to mention in your code :

- Use `ID` selector instead of `class` selector to find DOM node.
- Update the DOM only once. Changing the `innerHTML` inside the `map` is not efficient as you are triggering multiple `reflow`. We can do it in only one `reflow` by updating the `innerHTML` after the `map`. `Reflow` operation uses `CPU` and is more expensive than `repaint` operation. This might be an issue if the projects array is very large.

```js
function moreProj(projects) {
  let project = projects.map((project) => {
    const {
      image,
      title,
      desc,
      github,
      preview
    } = project;
    return `
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-img">
          <img src="${image}" class="img-fluuid" alt="project image">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="indicator">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-grip-lines"></i>
          </div>
          <h3 class="title">${title}</h3>
          <p class="desc">${desc}</p>
          <div class="links">
            <a href="${github}" class="link" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
              Github
            </a>
            <a href="${preview}" class="link" target="_blank">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
              Preview
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`;

  });

  return project;
}

const moreProjects = [{
    image: "./images/huddle-landing.jpg",
    title: "Huddle landing page",
    desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to practice my layout skills.",
    github: "https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-huddle-landingpage.git",
    preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-huddle-landingpage/",
  },
  {
    image: "./images/loopstudios-landing.jpg",
    title: "Loopstudios landing page",
    desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to practice my knowledge using CSS Grid.",
    github: "https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-loopstudio.git",
    preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-loopstudio/",
  },
  {
    image: "./images/pricingcomponent.jpg",
    title: "Pricing component",
    desc: "The challenge from frontend mentor, this helps me to increase my knowledge on JavaScript and how to style input range.",
    github: "https://github.com/hatwell-jonel/frontendmentor-pricingcomponent.git",
    preview: "https://hatwell-jonel.github.io/frontendmentor-pricingcomponent/",
  },
];

const carouselDOM = document.querySelector("#owl-carousel");
const projects = moreProj(moreProjects);
let template = "";

for (const project of projects) {
  template += project;
}

// Updating the DOM only once after all projects are processed
carouselDOM.innerHTML = template;
```

```html
<section class="carousel">
  <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <!-- RENDER ELEMENTS HERE -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't but it throws the same output. like the image about the question.

Comment: @user15314274 That's because I have not added any `CSS`. I only did the `Javascript` changes.

Comment: thank you for your help, it's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Code Edited:

```
 const carouselDOM = document.querySelector(".owl-carousel");

    function moreProj(projects) {
        let project = projects.map((project) => {
            const { image, title, desc, github, preview } = project;
            return `
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="${image}" class="img-fluuid" alt="project image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="indicator">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-grip-lines"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="title">${title}</h3>
                    <p class="desc">${desc}</p>
                    <div class="links">
                        <a href="${github}" class="link" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                        Github
                        </a>
                        <a href="${preview}" class="link" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
                        Preview
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
            
        });
        
        project = project.join("");
        carouselDOM.innerHTML = project;            
    }
```

Comment: I already edited the question. I just not added the }); after the return. thank you for the correction.